# Adding Predictors to random forest classifier (Pandas, Python3,Sklearn)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to learn how to use a random forest generator in Python by adapting code found here: http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/random-forests-in-python.html  to a fake data set

I'm trying to predict whether a person is male (0) or female (1) based on their weight and height

Data looks like so:

```
  Weight     Height     Gender
  150         60          1
  250         85          0
  175         75          0
  100         62          1
  90          58          1
  200         80          0
  ...         ...         ...
  165         66          0
```

Now I'm trying to classify the test set into male and female

Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

xl = pd.ExcelFile(fakedata.xlsx')
df = xl.parse()
df.head()
df['is_train'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(df)) <= .75
train, test = df[df['is_train']==True], df[df['is_train']==False]
features = df.columns[:2]
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=2)
y, _ = pd.factorize(train['Gender'])
clf.fit(train[features], y)
```

I understand what this code accomplishes up to here but I run into problems after:

```
preds = train['Gender'][clf.predict(test[features])]
print(pd.crosstab(test['Gender'], preds, rownames=['actual'], colnames=['preds']))
```

gives me the error

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

What exactly am I missing?

Comment: Please keep in mind, that with 2 independent variables (weight and height) your dataset is _not_ suited for RandomForest. I hope it was just a small reproducible example, not your real task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't index by the predictions in your line `preds = train['Gender'][clf.predict(test[features])]`. Your predictions should simply be

```
preds = clf.predict(test[features])
```